# Projecting the closure of functional dependencies over a relational set

Tags: database, closures, relational-database

I've read about closure for specific attributes and know how to get them. However I don't understand how to get following:

R(ABCDEF) 
**F=** 
A->BC, 
C->DE, 
E-> A

***Question:*** project F⁺ over S(ACE) (i.e. which FDs hold over S?)

Does this mean I should list all the functional dependencies from F such that they hold in S?

So E -> A is the only viable answer as both attributes are listed in S?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows basically same concept of obtaining the closures of a specific attribute. You just have to use the defined functional dependencies and find out the ones that are relevant to the the relation **S(ACE)** by simply using Armstrong's axioms. The axiom used below is the trasitivity axiom.

We can see that with A you can obtain 
A -> C 
A -> B // However this one is not relevant as B does not exist in ***S***. The ones not relevant to the relation ***S*** will be excluded
A -> E

With E:
E -> A 
E -> C

With C: 
C -> A 
C -> E

We have now gone through all attributes in the relation ***S*** therefore the closure of the functional dependencies over **S(ACE)** is: 
E -> AC 
A -> CE 
C -> AE